# use lodash to remove elements from nested array form start and from end

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have one nested array for example

```
var arr = [
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2,3],
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1]
];
```

How to remove N items from end or from beginning using lodash?

For example if I remove 6 elements from beginning, I want result to be:

```
var arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1]
];
```

and if I remove 1 from end, I need result to be:

```
var arr = [
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2,3],
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0]
];
```

I hope i was clear. Lodash is not necessary.

This is my code:

```
function removeFromTop(group, count) {
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < group[i].chatItems.length; x++) {
            if(count) {
                group[i].chatItems.splice(x, 1);
                if(!group[i].chatItems.length) {
                    group.splice(i, 1);
                };
                count--;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        };
    };
    return group;
}
function removeFromBottom(group, count) {
    for (var i = group.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var x = group[i].chatItems.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            if(count) {
                group[i].chatItems.splice(x, 1);
                if(!group[i].chatItems.length) {
                    group.splice(i, 1);
                };
                count--;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        };
    };
    return group;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? You don't need lodash for this, you should be good with [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and a for loop.

Comment: 1. create a `needToRemove = 6`. 2. create a loop while this variable is more than 0. 3. Check the length of the first nested array. If less than `needToRemove` - remove the whole array and decrease the `needToRemove` by that length 3b. Otherwise - only cut a part of the array.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: And just for fun, a recursive TC-optimisable solution: https://pastebin.com/yRsy9GcZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shift the inner array for each item count from the beginning and pop the values from the end. For the first you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and for the other [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)

```js
function removeFromStart(array, n) {
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
    return copy.reduce(function (r, a) {
        while (n && a.length) {
            a.shift();
            n--;
        }
        a.length && r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

function removeFromEnd(array, n) {
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
    return copy.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
        while (n && a.length) {
            a.pop();
            n--;
        }
        a.length && r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []).reverse();
}

var array = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1]];

console.log(JSON.stringify(removeFromStart(array, 6)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeFromEnd(array, 6)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @zerkms, it's better, to see the whole picture ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

using Lodash function [*.drop*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#drop) you can drop very first element(s) of an array or else can specify n element(s) default value is 1. same way  [.dropRight](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#dropRight) for the end element(s).

```js
var arr = [
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2,3],
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1]
];
// remove 1 element front  of 2D Array
var resultFront= arr.map(function(value,index) { return _.drop(value); });

console.log(resultFront);

// remove 1 element from End of 2D Array
var resultEnd= arr.map(function(value,index) { return _.dropRight(value); });

console.log(resultEnd);

// remove 1 element front and end  of 2D Array
var resultFrontEnd = arr.map(function(value,index) { return _.dropRight(_.drop(value)); });

console.log(resultFrontEnd);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var arr = [
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2,3],
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1]
];
console.log(arr);
console.log('------------------------');
// remove 1 element front  of 2D Array
var resultFront= arr.map(function(value,index) { return _.drop(value); });
console.log('Remove 1 element from front') ;
console.log(resultFront);

// remove 1 element from End of 2D Array
var resultEnd= arr.map(function(value,index) { return _.dropRight(value); });
console.log('Remove 1 element from end') ;
console.log(resultEnd);

// remove 1 element front and end  of 2D Array
var resultFrontEnd = arr.map(function(value,index) { return _.dropRight(_.drop(value)); });

console.log('Remove 1 element from front & End') ;
console.log(resultFrontEnd);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do as follows;

```js
var arr = [[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1]],
      r = [],
      n = 6,
    res = arr.reduce((r,sa) => r.n > sa.length ? (r.n -= sa.length, r)
                                               : (r.push(sa.slice(r.n)), r.n = 0, r), (r.n = n, r));
console.log(res);
```

I use a state variable `r.n` within the initial array in the reduce operation. You may or may not chose to delete it afterwards.